# How can I ignore test file in codeql?

Tags: ruby, codeql

I want to ignore test files in codeql result.
but this query includes test files.

```
import codeql.ruby.AST

from RegExpLiteral t,  File f
where not f.getBaseName().regexpMatch("spec")
select t
```

ignore test files in the result

Answer (score 0):

[`regexpMatch`](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-standard-libraries/ruby/predicate.string$regexpMatch.1.html) requires that the given pattern matches the *entire* receiver. In your case that means it would only succeed if the file name is exactly "spec". Maybe you rather want to test for `".*spec.*"` (or use [`matches("%spec%")`](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-standard-libraries/ruby/predicate.string$matches.1.html)).

I am not sure though if that answers your question. As far as I know there is in general no direct way to ignore test sources. You could however do one of the following things:

- Exclude the test directory when building the CodeQL database; for GitHub code scanning see the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning#specifying-directories-to-scan)
- For GitHub code scanning filter out non-application code alerts in the repository alerts list (see [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/managing-code-scanning-alerts-for-your-repository#restricting-results-to-application-code-only))
- Manually add conditions to your query which exclude tests, for example a file name check as you have done or checking the code for certain test-related constructs